# All our azure Sql server address point to the same place

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We had set up a resource group and Sql database and server for testing. Then we decided to create a new resource group and resources. Our original database was 'Mkp' on server 'mkp'.

Our new database was 'mkp-dev-db' on server 'mkp-dev-sql'. As soon as I created it and connected to the new server, I see the database from the first server (Mkp). I don't see the new database.

I tried it again, without the dashes, and specifically created a new sql server and selected blank database. I still see the original database with the new server connection, but neither of the new databases.

Here's what it looks like in SQL Management. Both connections have the same DB.

[image]

Comment: Check the login, I see in the screenshot 2 instances of the user 'mkpadmin@mkp', login at the new server with 'mkpadmin@mkp-dev-sql'

Comment: @ErikOppedijk, thank you. That was the answer. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the login, I see in the screenshot 2 instances of the user 'mkpadmin@mkp', login at the new server with 'mkpadmin@mkp-dev-sql'

SQL azure uses the login string as a selector for the database

```
<login>@<server>
```

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-logins/